# Does Fedora 32 no longer support the rpm-python package? If so, what took its place?

Tags: fedora, rpm

On older versions of Fedora, one could run the following command to install the rpm-python package:

> $ sudo dnf install rpm-python

But now on Fedora 32, it gives the following error:

> No match for argument: rpm-python Error: Unable to find a match:
>   rpm-python

Which package should one install now to get that same package or a similar one on their machine?

Comment: What version of Python are you using (2/3)? `python3-rpm` provides rpm access for python but might not be a direct replacement of rpm-python.

Comment: The code base I am working with is using a mixture of Python 2 and 3 so it is difficult to know whether this package is meant to be Python 2 or 3 in the first place. Your question is very good: is python3-rpm a direct replace of rpm-python? I'm not sure, yet.

Answer (score 1):

Fedora 31 has packages `python2-rpm` and `python3-rpm`. The package `rpm-python` does not exist for a long time. You can request installation of `rpm-python`, but DNF will actually install `python2-rpm`.

Fedora 32 moved to Python3 completely (there are some rare exceptions) and `python2-rpm` ceased to exists. There is only `python3-rpm` which has the same code. The same API. It is just for python3 only.